# Is openFrameworks a good choice for developing desktop gui applications?

Tags: c++, user-interface, desktop-application, openframeworks

I want to start a project in c++ and is looking for a good framework with all the good libraries for making a small GUI desktop software, I feel its good to stop a while and listen to you before kick off.
Also please suggest:

- if openFrameworks is a good choice?
- other good cpp frameworks (especially for GUI desktop application)

Comment: I was expecting your openion on why openframeword might not be the starting framework for gui, that has less to do with opengl and similar stuff, not any kind of debate or arguments at all. I really  don't find it reasonable to close this question :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends what you are trying to do.

for a simple application i would look into [wxWidgets](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/wxwidgetstutorial/firstprograms/) or qt

it seems like openframeworks is geard more towards opengl developement like for games